How to isolate nickel-chrome wire?
I want to heat up a stainless-steel pipe using a nickel-chrome wire by wrapping the wire around it and using a 12 V / 2 A DC adapter as a power source. I wrapped kapton around the pipe and also wrapped a heat shrink around kapton, then I wrapped the nickel-chrome wire around them.
The staff is working perfectly, but when I check the steel with a test screwdriver, the lamp lights up. When I check with voltmeter, it reads about 20 V AC when one prob touch the steel pipe and one in my hand.
I don't know what is the source of electricity, even there is no short between the wire and the steel.
The heat needed is about 80°C

measure the current the same as you do voltage, i'll bet it's next to nothing. If so, don't worry about it, it's stray/phantom voltage.

Use glass-fiber tape, not kapton, unless the temperature is quite low. Also, use something to keep the wires from slipping, after repeated heating and cooling, such as furnace cement (or if temp is not above 100°C, silicone of epoxy cement).

Khalident, Go to the Cotronics web site and find what you need there. They have exactly what you need to use. And the pricing is fine and the quality excellent. Unless there's something you didn't mention, you won't need the wire insulation. You can just bury the nichrome wire itself directly into ceramic, thermal conducting, electrically insulating paste. Just make sure to put down a layer over the steel pipe first before wrapping with nichrome and potting the wire.

Khalident, The white ceramic material is also somewhat better to reduce radiation into the environment (quicker and cheaper heating.) It's matte, though. A more specular coating (an added aluminum or silver spray coating?) may further help. That said, you may need several thermal controllers -- just looking at that beast. Not sure a single-point of measurement and control will create much uniformity. The inner pipes will not have the same radiation to the outside world as the pipes on the perimeter. But that's your call. You know what you need to achieve. I don't.

Sounds like Y-capacitor leakage.

Measure the voltage from each leg of the 24V supply to the metal part.
If you get close to zero don't worry, your non-contact detector is just picking up the phantom voltage from your 24V supply.
If you don't get close to zero, check the resistance between the nichrome and the stainless.
commercial products often use mineral insulation (eg: mica) between the nichrome and the part to be heated.
